# Object with ID 'assetID:5326' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.acme.mynetwork.Sensor' does not exist

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

**my model is this:**

```js
namespace org.acme.mynetwork
asset Sensor identified by assetID {
    o String assetID
    o String Frequency
    o String longitude
    o String latutide
    o String name
    --> Spectrum range
}
participant Spectrum identified by SpectrumId {
    o String SpectrumId
    o String Spectrumval
}

transaction SpectrumChange {
    --> Sensor sensor 
    --> Spectrum newrange
}
```

**My sample.js file contains:**

```js
/**
 * Track the trade of a commodity from one trader to another
 * @param {org.acme.mynetwork.SpectrumChange} Change - the spectrum to be processed
 * @transaction
 */
function Spectrumupdate(spectrumChange) {
    spectrumChange.sensor.range = spectrumChange.newrange;
    return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.mynetwork.Sensor')
        .then(function (assetRegistry) {
            return assetRegistry.update(spectrumChange.sensor);
        });
}
```

**When I test is I am getting this error:**
Error: Object with ID 'assetID:0138' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.acme.mynetwork.Sensor' does not exist
The issue is that I have created this ID and i can see that asset in there. can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this a few days ago. Remove 'assetID:' from your test string.

For example,

'org.acme.mynetwork#assetID:5326'
becomes
'org.acme.mynetwork#5326'

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the user you are trying to access is not there in the records. Please revisit the page and check the ID (assetID/Account/EmpId/..) which you have provided.

When I faced this issue there was a typo while creating the records. The CustomerID while doing the transaction and the CustomerID I created were different.